# How to display data using $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

i need some help. its basic coding but the code still wont display my data stored. 
here is my code: if someone can help me and explain. i've read the documentation and i followed it but it wont display my data. the code wont display my data stored in wp_options. is there something i am missing?

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = '262'
    ", ARRAY_A);
print_r($result);
}
?>
```

it just displays a blank screen.

Comment: In your `php.ini` do you have error messages showing? Sometimes blank page is because an error occurred but you're php.ini file is set to not display errors. Also where is this snippet being used?

Comment: See this link for turning on error_reporting in your php file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096

Comment: okay @Gohn67. i'll check it out. sorry. noob coder here.

Comment: Well...you definitely have a stray curly brace... `}`

Comment: @rnevius i removed the stray brace. still blank page.

Comment: Are you adding this code in a separate php file? Or is this in a template or funtions.php?. If you are just adding it as a separate php file, $wpdb won't be recognized since that code is not included automatically.

Comment: yes @Gohn67 this is a separate php file. for testing purposes. saw the php error. "Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/hello-world/display-data.php on line 4"

Comment: Yeah for Wordpress, it's easiest to just do it in the theme/plugin. That way all the Wordpress functions are loaded for you.

Comment: but i am trying to create a plugin though. cant seem to connect to the database using $wpdb.

Comment: Yeah, you can do it in a plugin too, but you need to enable the plugin in Wordress. You can't go to: `/plugins/hello-world/display-data.‌​php` directly. Just go to to the home page and it should print something. Kind of hacky, but add a `die();` after `print_r` to better see the result.